# Multi-function memoizator and multi-type container

Tags: c++, collections, type-safety, memoization

I'm trying to write a multiple functions memoizator, which I've talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759124/containers-for-different-signature-functions). The main problem is creating a container containing different and heterogenous functions.

I found a working solution, but I don't know if it's safe, if there are limitations, if it's somehow inefficient or if there is a more elegant solution.

This is my solution:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
function<ReturnType(Args...)> memoize(function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
{
    return ([=](Args... args) mutable {
        static map<tuple<Args...>, ReturnType> cache;
        tuple<Args...> t(args...);
        auto result = cache.insert(make_pair(t, ReturnType{}));
        if (result.second) {
            // insertion succeeded so the value wasn't cached already
            result.first->second = func(args...);
        }
        return result.first->second;
    });
}

struct MultiMemoizator
{
    map<string, boost::any> multiCache;
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    void addFunction(string name, function < ReturnType(Args...)> func) {
        function < ReturnType(Args...)> cachedFunc = memoize(func);
        boost::any anyCachedFunc = cachedFunc;
        auto result = multiCache.insert(pair<string, boost::any>(name,anyCachedFunc));
        if (!result.second)
            cout << "ERROR: key " + name + " was already inserted" << endl;
    }
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(string name, Args... args) {
        auto it = multiCache.find(name);
        if (it == multiCache.end())
            throw KeyNotFound(name);
        boost::any anyCachedFunc = it->second;
        function < ReturnType(Args...)> cachedFunc = boost::any_cast<function<ReturnType(Args...)>> (anyCachedFunc);
        return cachedFunc(args...);
    }
};
```

And this is a possible main:

```
int main()
{
    function<int(int)> intFun = [](int i) {return ++i; };
    function<string(string)> stringFun = [](string s) {
        return "Hello "+s;
    };
    MultiMemoizator mem;
    mem.addFunction("intFun",intFun);
    mem.addFunction("stringFun", stringFun);
    try
    {
        cout << mem.callFunction<int, int>("intFun", 1)<<endl;//print 2
        cout << mem.callFunction<string, string>("stringFun", " World!") << endl;//print Hello World!
        cout << mem.callFunction<string, string>("TrumpIsADickHead", " World!") << endl;//KeyNotFound thrown
    }
    catch (boost::bad_any_cast e)
    {
        cout << "Bad function calling: "<<e.what()<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (KeyNotFound e) 
    {
        cout << e.what()<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary `#include` lines, both in the code for review and in the sample program (it seems you need Boost, but never mentioned that in the description).

Comment: The only issue I see here is what happens if your lambdas goes out of scope. If it is n't meant to be global current impl is memory safe. If you turn on c++17 then you'll be able to get rid of boost and use structural bindings. Also you probably don't need explicitly pass types to your `callFunction`

Answer (score 1):

To make this even compile, I needed to add several standard-library includes:

```
#include <any>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
```

I also needed to add the `std::` namespace prefix in many places.  (Don't be tempted to `using namespace std` - **especially** in your header files, where that would affect all your users!)

---

### `memoize()`

This looks like a straightforward memoization function.  It's probably worthwhile to constrain it to work only with functions with no internal state and which return copyable values.

It's a shame the caller needs to provide a `std::function` - I'd like to be able to accept any `std::regular_invocable` here, but we need something with a known argument list, which we can't deduce in the general case (I think).

It seems that we need the `ReturnType` to be default-constructible.  We can avoid this by first looking for the key, and only inserting if not found.

We're copying the argument tuple more than is necessary, which could be expensive (e.g. for `std::string` arguments).  We should use `std::move` when storing the tuple as map key.

We have a serious **bug** because the cache is a function-static variable, meaning that it's shared by *all functions with the same signature*.  That's a fundamental flaw, and should have been discovered during testing.  The fix is to make it a member of the closure, with a capture that copy-initialises.

Here's my rewritten `memoize()`:

```
#include <concepts>

template <std::copyable ReturnType, typename... Args>
auto memoize(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
    -> decltype(func)
{
    return [func, cache = std::map<std::tuple<Args...>, ReturnType>{}](Args... args) mutable {
        typename decltype(cache)::key_type t(args...);
        auto it = cache.lower_bound(t);
        if (it == cache.end() || it->first != t) {
            it = cache.emplace_hint(it, std::move(t), func(args...));
        }
        return it->second;
    };
}
```

---

### `MultiMemoizator`

This doesn't seem as useful to me.  I can't see how calling functions by name (and having to specify their signatures every time) is any great advantage.  And I don't see why this needs to be tied in to the memoization functionality - why not simply store *any* function, and just return that, to be called or manipulated however required?  The call would look quite similar, just swapping a comma for some parens e.g. `mem.callFunction<int, int>("intFun")(1)`.

When looking up a function by name, we don't need a copy of the name - pass a const reference instead.

It's interesting that we report "not found" by exception, but just ignore (with a warning message) attempts to add a function that's already present.  Users would probably prefer consistency - I'd suggest throwing in both cases.  And consider using `std::out_of_range` for a lookup failure, as `std::map::at()` does.

Avoid storing `std::string` in custom exceptions - the standard library exceptions all use `const char*` for the message.  This reduces the likelihood of exception handlers throwing (e.g. by copying the string and getting `std::bad_alloc`), which as we all know is unhandleable and causes program termination.

There's a serious **bug** in `callFunction()` (that was masked by the `static` cache in `memoize`): `std::any_cast()`, like `boost::any_cast()`, returns a *copy* of the stored function.  To keep the memoization, we need to return the function back to the map after we've called it.

Improved code:

```
class MultiMemoizator
{
    std::map<std::string, std::any> functions = {};

public:
    struct duplicate_key_error : public std::logic_error {
        duplicate_key_error(const char *msg) : std::logic_error{msg} {}
    };

    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    void addFunction(std::string name, std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func)
    {
        auto result = functions.try_emplace(std::move(name), memoize(func));
        if (!result.second) {
            // N.B. name was not moved from if try_emplace failed
            throw duplicate_key_error(name.c_str());
        }
    }

    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(const std::string& name, Args... args)
    {
        auto it = functions.find(name);
        if (it == functions.end()) {
            throw std::out_of_range(name.c_str());
        }
        using function_type = std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>;
        auto cachedFunc = std::any_cast<function_type> (it->second);
        auto const result = cachedFunc(args...);
        it->second = cachedFunc; // we possibly modified our copy of the function
        return result;
    }
};
```

---

The `main()` function misses some key tests, as noted above.  It doesn't even demonstrate that values are actually being stored and retrieved.  We can easily do that by passing a function that produces output when it is called.

Note that nothing except programmer discipline stops us attempting to memoize functions which don't act like `constexpr` functions, such as this simple example:

```
std::function<int(int)> badFun = [](int i){ static int n = 0; return i + ++n; };
```

I don't see anything we can usefully do to avoid that.